# Read text from an image with PHP

Tags: php, image

I would like to try to read some of text from an image with PHP.

So if I have an image like this:

[image]

How can I extract the text "Some text" into a string.

All help and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You can use Tesseract OCR library . https://www.tutsplanet.com/how-to-read-text-from-image-in-php/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The process you are looking for is called Optical Character Recognition.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition

There is a package available, called phpOCR, that does exactly what you need.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpocr/

Comment: I have tried phpOCR but it is not working. The script has two functions imagecreatefrompng and imagecreatefromjpeg which are not defined and hence gives an error.

Comment: @san you need to install php-gd library

Answer (score 19):

phpOCR ist not the best choice, I would recommend TesseractOCR for PHP "A wrapper to work with TesseractOCR inside your PHP scripts."
https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php

Answer (score 9):

That's called OCR. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition ).

It's not a trival task (that's why captcha's work as good as they do).

You'd be better of googling 'OCR PHP' if you want to find solutions.

Comment: This is a funny thing. Googling "_php ocr image to text_" brings this same question right on top of the results. So meta (or an oxymoron, if you prefer so)

Comment: The captchas work so well that I can't read them