# How to read text from images

Tags: java, php, javascript

Hey guys is it possible to read text from an image, like how you go to submit a form and it ask you to fill in the text inside image.  I want to know if it is possible to read the text inside it. If so, what language?

David Biga

EDIT:

I am not trying to read captcha I was just giving an example of an image with text in it.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2024238/1190388) is another thread with similar question.

Comment: Just so I get this right... you are trying to get help with circumventing CAPTCHAs?  Good luck. :)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to read text with [Optical Character Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition).

However, [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)s are designed to thwart this, in order to distinguish humans from computers.

Comment: Not a captcha but from an image...I was just trying to give an example

Comment: Andy is there any code sources on this?

Comment: Here's a previous question covering simple OCR without CAPTCHAs -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813881/java-ocr-implementation. It's the first result when googling "Java OCR libraries", once you know the OCR acronym.