# Reading Image for circled text

Tags: php, gd

I have an image and want to read it for the circled text in it.

We need to take our the circled text only.

Is there any example on the attached image, please?[image]

Comment: OCR is no simple task. You can take a look at this OCR library - http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2874-PHP-Recognize-text-objects-in-graphical-images.html

Comment: Is this possible?Let me know also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024238/read-text-from-an-image-with-php This may help you.

Comment: I do not think PHPOCR will help extracting circled text from image.

Answer (score 2):

If you are 100% sure, that text will be circled, you can do following:

1) Extract edges from image (that will filter out some noise and preserve outlines)

2) Convert image to binary. You know, that foreground has colors bigger than lets say (250, 250, 250). So every color with components bigger that that will be 0, other 1

3) Now find vertical and horizontal lines in image. Those lines are 100% straight and longer than "tresshold" value (otherwise, you will get lines from letters, but those are always shorter, because circle covers more than one letter)

[image]

4) After you found whose lines, track its contour and find full "circle"

5) Get inner area of circle and extract it from original image

6) For area you got, you have to use OCR to extract letters from it

Comment: Yes it is damn sure that text will be circled but with different positions. Your preferred steps seem to be logical to me. I would love if you can please prepare a sample? Can you?

Comment: I dont have much time... but programm that by provided steps should be sraightforward. It just takes some time.