# count number of characters in image in php

Tags: php, image

I have an image which contains text lines. I want to count number of characters or number of lines in image using php or jquery or javascript.
Please give me any link or any solution for this.

Thanks

Comment: here is the link which may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024238/read-text-from-an-image-with-php

Comment: you cant read text content of  an image file from jquery or php. for this you need some advance technology like OCR etc.

Answer (score 0):

phpOCR

phpOCR is a simple optical character recognizer. 
It works with numbers by default but any
character support is available with custom
templates.
It has features such as:
- image upload
- remote image by URL
- html output type
- plaintext output type
- xml output type
- easy to create templates for different fonts
- jpg, png and gif support (with PHP/GD and gif2png libraries)
Works well with automated setups.

Found this two helpful links -

http://phpocr.sourceforge.net/

https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php